# Xamarin iOS build fails from TFS for iPhone with signing key error

Tags: macos, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, tfs-2015

Xamarin iOS build fails with error as "error: iOS code signing key 'iPhone Distribution: ******* (**********)' not found in keychain" when doing build from TFS 2015 for iPhone. I am able to do the build from local and get the message for signing identity being deteted.

I checked the keychain on my mac, and the key is present in there. I am not using any custom entitlements.

I looked up for solutions of similar posts on stackoverflow, but none of them is working for me.

Comment: How about build for iOS Simulator? Do you renew your yearly developer account with Apple recently?

Comment: Did you try to build it from the build agent manually?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT The build is successful for iOS simulator from TFS. I am able to do the build locally for both iPhone and iOS simulator. It is failing for iPhone. The membership was renewed in March 2016.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT  I am not sure how to do the build from agent manually. Can you please guide me so that i can try?

Comment: @VishalAgarwal Just copy your project to the build agent and then run the build manually.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT The build is working from agent manually but still failing from TFS.

Comment: @VishalAgarwal Does your build agent run as service or run in interactive mode? Refer to this link for details: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/v2-osx#run-interactively

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT It is running as service. I got it working after adding it to the System keychain and giving it Trust permissions. Thank you for all your help. :)

Comment: @VishalAgarwal I am running into the same issue, can you please describe what you did? I am fairly new to the Mac world. Also, what is the "it" that you were referring? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you renewed your yearly developer account with Apple recently, you may check the solution on [this website](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/63318#Comment_63318), just do the following:

- If it's open, stop Xamarin Studio (or the Xamarin Build Host if
  running in Visual Studio).
- Start Xcode.
- From the Xcode menu select Preferences....
- Select Accounts from the Preference Dialog.
- Click the View Details... button.
- Under the Signing Identities list, click the + button.
- Select iOS Development from the popup list, Xcode will contact Apple
  and issue a new license which will appear in the Signing Identities
  list.
- Next click on the + button again and select iOS Distribution from the
  popup list.
- Again, Xcode will contact Apple, issue a new license and display it
  in the Signing Identities list.
- Click the Done button and close the Preference Dialog.
- Quit Xcode and restart Xamarin Studio (or the Build Host if using
  Visual Studio).

In your Xamarin project you might have to open the preferences select iOS Bundle Signing > Identity and select a new identity from the list of available identities.

If you are using Visual Studio and a Xamarin Build Host, you might have to disconnect from the host and reconnect to see the change in the signing identities.

Comment: "Under the Signing Identities list, click the + button." There is no plus button inside. It is present when i select preferences from Xcode menu. My account is already added and i tried resigning as well. I can see my certificate and key in the keychain under login. Not sure why TFS is giving the error. The build is successful from local.